# Function for linear interpolation of data points based on a fixed continuous increase in the time-variable

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, interpolation

I have three treatment groups stored in `CIF` in my data `res`. Based on the reproducible example:

```
> table(res$CIF)

Control     SSA    SSTR 
     35      25       5
```

For each `res$CIF`, there is an estimated probability `res$P` of an outcome at time `res$time`. The probability comes with a 95%-CI as in `res$lower` and `res$upper`.

Hence

```
> head(res,10)
     CIF          P time       lower     upper
 1: SSTR 0.12500000 1.00 0.032811154 0.4140186
 2: SSTR 0.31250000 2.00 0.143720822 0.5953967
 3: SSTR 0.62500000 3.00 0.402281539 0.8457738
 4: SSTR 0.81250000 4.00 0.597544067 0.9539839
 5: SSTR 0.87500000 5.00 0.672015645 0.9793250
 6:  SSA 0.02777778 0.72 0.003960129 0.1812693
 7:  SSA 0.08333333 1.00 0.027663184 0.2365298
 8:  SSA 0.11111111 1.02 0.043219272 0.2694809
 9:  SSA 0.13888889 1.08 0.060294215 0.3020083
10:  SSA 0.16666667 1.48 0.078561410 0.3338737
```

I need to interpolate `res$P` and the corresponding `res$lower` + `res$upper` linearly at time points not currently given in `res$time`.

I am looking for a function (or similar solutions - perhaps a solution in `dplyr`?) that expand `res` so that `res$time` ranges from `0` to the maximum `res$time` for each `res$CIF`. The `res$time` should increase continuously by `.01`.

Ie, from `0` to `105.16`, `30.85` and `5.00` by `.01`, respectively:

```
> tapply(res$time,res$CIF,max)
Control     SSA    SSTR 
 105.16   30.85    5.00
```

An example of the expected output

```
# Before interpolation 
> head(res[res$CIF=="SSA"],5)
   CIF          P time       lower     upper
1: SSA 0.02777778 0.72 0.003960129 0.1812693
2: SSA 0.08333333 1.00 0.027663184 0.2365298
3: SSA 0.11111111 1.02 0.043219272 0.2694809
4: SSA 0.13888889 1.08 0.060294215 0.3020083
5: SSA 0.16666667 1.48 0.078561410 0.3338737
```

Should give something like

```
CIF           P   time       lower        upper
SSA           0   0.00           0            0 
SSA interpolate   0.01 interpolate  interpolate
(....)
SSA  0.02777778   0.72 0.003960129    0.1812693
(....)
SSA  0.08333333   1.00 0.027663184    0.2365298
SSA interpolate   1.01 interpolate  interpolate
SSA  0.11111111   1.02 0.043219272    0.2694809
SSA interpolate   1.03 interpolate  interpolate
SSA interpolate   1.04 interpolate  interpolate
SSA interpolate   1.05 interpolate  interpolate
SSA interpolate   1.06 interpolate  interpolate
SSA interpolate   1.07 interpolate  interpolate
SSA  0.13888889   1.08 0.060294215    0.3020083
```

My data `res`

```
res <- structure(list(CIF = c("SSTR", "SSTR", "SSTR", "SSTR", "SSTR", 
"SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", 
"SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", 
"SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "SSA", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control"), P = c(0.125, 0.3125, 0.625, 
0.8125, 0.875, 0.0277777777777778, 0.0833333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
0.138888888888889, 0.166666666666667, 0.305555555555556, 0.361111111111111, 
0.388888888888889, 0.416666666666667, 0.444444444444445, 0.472222222222222, 
0.527777777777778, 0.555555555555556, 0.583333333333333, 0.613095238095238, 
0.642857142857143, 0.672619047619048, 0.672619047619048, 0.732142857142857, 
0.761904761904762, 0.791666666666667, 0.821428571428572, 0.858630952380953, 
0.895833333333333, 0.970238095238095, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 
0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2, 0.225, 
0.25, 0.275, 0.3, 0.325, 0.35, 0.375, 0.4, 0.425, 0.45, 0.478333333333333, 
0.506666666666667, 0.535, 0.565909090909091, 0.596818181818182, 
0.631590909090909, 0.666363636363636, 0.701136363636364, 0.735909090909091, 
0.770681818181818, 0.805454545454545, 0.840227272727273), time = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 0.72, 1, 1.02, 1.08, 1.48, 2, 2.76, 2.82, 2.83, 3, 
3.08, 3.57, 5.07, 5.49, 8.03, 9, 9.2, 9.25, 10.8, 11, 11.04, 
14.2, 15.05, 21.42, 30.85, 0.23, 0.26, 0.49, 0.53, 0.69, 3.15, 
3.25, 4.5, 5.12, 5.78, 6.67, 7.65, 7.79, 7.85, 9, 9.99, 11.37, 
12.68, 13.11, 15.05, 15.83, 16.89, 18.17, 22.7, 23.59, 29.6, 
32.65, 35.81, 43, 43.79, 45.37, 46.45, 46.65, 69.02, 105.16), 
    lower = c(0.0328111539708764, 0.143720822077878, 0.402281538850257, 
    0.597544067030214, 0.672015645447537, 0.00396012891352548, 
    0.0276631838805069, 0.0432192720492351, 0.0602942151317983, 
    0.0785614100173507, 0.18231512406141, 0.228150254051563, 
    0.251830579852024, 0.275990636539769, 0.300615683301302, 
    0.32569554091635, 0.377199241260733, 0.403622389357051, 0.430498943169836, 
    0.45921123839169, 0.48851369241709, 0.518429809974778, 0.518429809974778, 
    0.580243253031609, 0.612241368451204, 0.645062949439568, 
    0.678811652981003, 0.718192077960655, 0.761035083198697, 
    0.86875565093952, 0.00355981698627006, 0.00355981698627006, 
    0.00355981698627006, 0.00355981698627006, 0.00355981698627006, 
    0.0127444761396915, 0.0248237564000704, 0.0387548083597935, 
    0.0540289278928447, 0.0703518337133965, 0.0703518337133965, 
    0.0875349177801499, 0.105448804967606, 0.124000413393049, 
    0.143120415258911, 0.162755851975246, 0.182865529959695, 
    0.20341701986178, 0.22438463188234, 0.245748013164318, 0.267491158005832, 
    0.289601702577961, 0.312070423267255, 0.337084153386502, 
    0.362632734261147, 0.388713550110491, 0.417009262625303, 
    0.446060748331539, 0.478344299849033, 0.511927776545623, 
    0.546903575783177, 0.583428286459313, 0.621755981338108, 
    0.662308487815083, 0.705837515898454), upper = c(0.414018563190984, 
    0.595396721303893, 0.845773808747176, 0.953983876394769, 
    0.979324974514942, 0.181269269945454, 0.236529759895451, 
    0.269480930499581, 0.302008337476789, 0.333873667543882, 
    0.483459160112475, 0.539346001089099, 0.566541091565836, 
    0.593255777919075, 0.619498863619302, 0.645275418976181, 
    0.695431242848002, 0.719802607844794, 0.743691288858428, 
    0.769343219994671, 0.794279647503738, 0.818479990760844, 
    0.818479990760844, 0.864527983506889, 0.886263823263894, 
    0.907030011614637, 0.926703065538918, 0.951295364401731, 
    0.971948922997515, 0.997717755344036, 0.164514540888494, 
    0.164514540888494, 0.164514540888494, 0.164514540888494, 
    0.164514540888494, 0.185453879855473, 0.214782436042548, 
    0.244858945502003, 0.274592902916402, 0.303763783420835, 
    0.303763783420835, 0.332343773644891, 0.360355238540763, 
    0.387832132523894, 0.414808316400823, 0.441314057995926, 
    0.467375240079267, 0.493013472868414, 0.518246474164134, 
    0.543088485840094, 0.56755064509021, 0.591641285440807, 0.615366163389952, 
    0.642996938577391, 0.669919078034907, 0.696160621236471, 
    0.724897048548371, 0.752630120302531, 0.78395657751485, 0.813600779732339, 
    0.841596636148257, 0.867931528334935, 0.892542509012415, 
    0.91530398695896, 0.935999137248638)), row.names = c(NA, 
-65L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `complete` from `tidyr` and `na.approx` from `zoo`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
res %>%
  group_by(CIF) %>%
  complete(time = seq(0, max(time), by = 0.01)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(P,lower,upper),
            .funs = list(~ifelse(time == 0 & is.na(.), 0, .))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(P,lower,upper),
            .funs = list(~ zoo::na.approx(.)))
```

If you wanted to use a non-linear approach, you might try `spline`:

```
res %>%
  group_by(CIF) %>%
  complete(time = seq(0, max(time), by = 0.01)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(P,lower,upper),
            .funs = list(~ifelse(time == 0 & is.na(.), 0, .))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(P,lower,upper),
            .funs = list(~ spline(time, . ,n=n())$y))
```

This doesn't replace the `NA`s, but instead replaces *all* the values with the interpolated ones.

Comment: Hi @IanCampell. Thank you very much - exactly what I requested. It is much appreciated! Would there be a similar alternative if one were to consider a non-linear approach more appropriate for the interpolation? I've just read about the `spline` option in `dplyr`, so I am asking with the intention of learning about `linear` vs `non-linear` interpolation, which currently is above my current level of skills.

Comment: Hi @IanCampell. Thank you for helping me with this issue. My apologies for asking, but I hope that you can help me with this spin-off question. So I tried to apply the script on the probability `res$P`, ie. the interpolation should be on `res$P` yielding corresponding `res$time`, `res$lower` and `res$upper`. I simply swapped the `P` and `time` in the script for linear interpolation, but the outcome looks really weird and wrong. Am I doing something wrong when swapping those two? The probability should increase from `0` to `max(P)` by `.01`. Thank you in advance!